# libxml2 fails to parse from buffer but parses successfully from file

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have a function that writes an XML document to a buffer using the libxml2 writer, but when I try to parse the document from memory using xmlParseMemory, it only returns parser errors.  I have also tried writing the document to a file and parsing it using xmlParseFile and it parses successfully.

This is how I initialize the writer and buffer for the xml document.

```
  int rc, i = 0;
  xmlTextWriterPtr writer;
  xmlBufferPtr buf;

  // Create a new XML buffer, to which the XML document will be written
  buf = xmlBufferCreate();
  if (buf == NULL)
  {
    printf("testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml buffer\n");
    return;
  }

  // Create a new XmlWriter for memory, with no compression.
  // Remark: there is no compression for this kind of xmlTextWriter
  writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(buf, 0);
  if (writer == NULL)
  {
    printf("testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml writer\n");
    return;
  }

  // Start the document with the xml default for the version,
  // encoding UTF-8 and the default for the standalone
  // declaration.
  rc = xmlTextWriterStartDocument(writer, NULL, ENCODING, NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    printf
    ("testXmlwriterMemory: Error at xmlTextWriterStartDocument\n");
    return;
  }
```

I pass the xml document to another function to be validated using
`int ret = validateXML(buf->content);`

Here is the first part of validateXML

```
int validateXML(char *buffer)
{
xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr ctxt;
char *XSDFileName = XSDFILE;
char *XMLFile = buffer;
int ret = 1;

doc = xmlReadMemory(XMLFile, sizeof(XMLFile), "noname.xml", NULL, 0);
```

doc is always NULL after calling this function, which means that it failed to parse the document.

Here are the errors that running the program returns

```
Entity: line 1: parser error : ParsePI: PI xm space expected
<?xm
    ^
Entity: line 1: parser error : ParsePI: PI xm never end ...
<?xm
    ^
Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
<?xm
    ^
```

I have been unable to figure this out for quite a while now and I am out of ideas.  If anyone has any, I would be grateful if you would share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `sizeof` to determine the size of the xml data. For a char pointer that is always going to return 4. What you probably need is `strlen`.

```
doc = xmlReadMemory(XMLFile, strlen(XMLFile), "noname.xml", NULL, 0);
```

Comment: It's always the smallest details that I overlook that cause the biggest problems. Thanks for pointing that out.